# React fetch more data and append to state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I have a problem with a classic infinite scroll, when loading more data and appending to the state.

I have a page that displays, among other things, a custom infinite scrollable list of cities.
The cities are fetched from an external library.

```js
import { City, Country, CitiesQuery } from "an-external-library";

export const CountryComponent: FC<Props> = ({ country: Country }) => {
  const [cities, setCities] = useState<City[]>([]);
  const [citiesQuery, setCitiesQuery] = useState<CitiesQuery>();

  const loadMoreCities = useCallback(() => {
    console.log("loadMoreCities", "cities", cities);

    citiesQuery
      ?.load((newCities) => {
        console.log("loadMoreCities", "newCities", newCities);
        const updatedCities = [...cities, ...newCities];
        console.log("loadMoreCities", "updatedCities", updatedCities);
        setCities(updatedCities);
      })
      .then(() => setCitiesQuery(citiesQuery))
      .catch(console.error)
  }, [cities]); // I've tried adding more dependencies here

  useEffect(() => {
    const query = country.createCitiesQuery()
    query.limit = 3; // example
    query
      .load(setCities)
      .then(() => setCitiesQuery(query)) // so that I can load more from where I left
      .catch(console.error)
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    // so that we know what's actually being set
    console.log("cities", cities);
  }, [cities])

  return (
    <>
      // ...
      <CitiesList cities={cities} onScrollBottom={loadMoreCities}/>
    </>
  )
}
```

My problem is that the `loadMoreCities` function doesn't seem to be updating when `cities` changes so, inside `loadMoreCities`, `cities` is always the same and doesn't reflect previous appends.

Here's an example run through logs:

```js
// initial render
cities: Array(0) []

// after first useEffect runs
cities: Array(3) ["A", "B", "C"]

// scroll bottom
loadMoreCities, cities: Array(3) ["A", "B", "C"]
loadMoreCities, newCities: Array(3) ["D", "E", "F"]
loadMoreCities, updatedCities: Array(6) ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"]
cities: Array(6) ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"]

// scroll bottom again
loadMoreCities, cities: Array(3) ["A", "B", "C"]  // <---- this is a problem
loadMoreCities, newCities: Array(3) ["G", "H", "I"]
loadMoreCities, updatedCities: Array(6) ["A", "B", "C", "G", "H", "I"]
cities: Array(6) ["A", "B", "C", "G", "H", "I"] // <---- as consequence, we lost ["D", "E", "F"]
```

I've tried adding all possible combinations of dependencies in the `useCallback`, but nothing seemed to work.
I'm sure I'm missing something really simple, but can't see what.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Solution

Try:

```
.load((newCities) => {
  setCities(cities => [...cities, ...newCities]);
})
```

Instead of:

```
.load((newCities) => {
  setCities([...cities, ...newCities]);
})
```

### Explanation

`setState` can take a value or a setter function

Consecutive calls with a value will result in only the last applied

```
const [state, setState] = useState([])

setState([...state, 'a']) // current state = []
setState([...state, 'a']) // current state = []
setState([...state, 'c']) // current state = []
// the result will be `['c']`
```

Using setter callback will make react remember each one and then run each with updated data

```
const [state, setState] = useState([])

setState(state => [...state, 'a']) // current state = []
setState(state => [...state, 'a']) // current state = ['a']
setState(state => [...state, 'c']) // current state = ['a', 'b']
// the result will be `['a', 'b', 'c']`
```

Comment: That's exactly what I have.

Comment: Updated the question to show the difference

Comment: Oh, you were right, it wasn't the same (sorry, too tired...). Thanks! It worked!

Comment: Can you explain why one works and the other doesn't (so that I learn and not just get the right answer)?

Comment: Reason: https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous

Comment: Thanks! It seems that with this solution, I don't even need the `useCallback`.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this to access directly the current state when updating it :

```js
setCities((currentCities) => {
 return [currentCities, ...newCities]
});
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked! But can you explain me why one works and the other doesn't?

Comment: sure, since the cities parameter of useCallback don't directly change until the load function get call it will end up being stale, when you use setState(variable => function) the `variable` parameter is the current state and not an outdated version :) @MarcoCastanho